# htaccess and htpasswd

Tags: admin, wp-admin, htaccess

im trying to lock my admin panel from my users with adding htpsswrd file to wp-admin folder. but also i want my users can edit their profiles. so i create this file (htaccess)

AuthName "Username and password required"
AuthUserFile ...../wp-admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
AuthType Basic

Order deny,allow
Allow from all
satisfy any

which works but, now when i try to access profiles, the site still askes password but also i can login. i think there are more files behind.

anyone know profile.php is using which files behind other than (user-edit.php)|(profile.php)|(users.php)

Comment: Review this post by Ipstenu for tips: WordPress Login Protection With .htaccess at http://halfelf.org/2013/wp-login-protection-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Your behavior is logical. the `profile.php` page is in the protected `/wp-admin/` folder.
the `wp-login.php` is in the root (`/`), which is not protected.

Answer (score 0):

You can add protection to individual files like (in your htaccess file):

```
<Files test.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
<Files test2.php>
require valid-user
</Files>
```